# How to filter a pandas dataframe based on the values in an external list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe. I want to compare each of the comma separated values from column `a` against the values in the `values` and return `True` if any one of the values is present in the column `a`. Hope you understand the scenario. Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
values = ['value 1', 'value 2']

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['value 1', 'value 1, value 2', 'value 1, value 3', 'value 3', 'value 4', 'value 5']})

                  a
0           value 1
1  value 1, value 2
2  value 1, value 3
3           value 3
4           value 4
5           value 5
```

I am expecting this to be returned:

```
    a
0   True
1   True
2   True
3   False
4   False
5   False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try `split` with `any`

```
df['b']=df.a.str.split(', ',expand=True).isin(values ).any(1)
df
Out[168]: 
                  a      b
0           value 1   True
1  value 1, value 2   True
2  value 1, value 3   True
3           value 3  False
4           value 4  False
5           value 5  False
```

Comment: What's the purpose of expand=True here?

Comment: @UmarAftab making the split row in to a dataframe ~ ~ https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html